# AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'all_sprites'

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the error I am getting:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\RPG Game\main.py", line 67, in <module>
>    g.new()
>  File "C:\RPG Game\main.py", line 23, in new
>    self.createTilemap()
>  File "C:\RPG Game\main.py", line 17, in createTilemap
>    Block(self, j, i)
>  File "C:\RPG Game\sprites.py", line 60, in __init__
>    self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.blocks
> AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'all_sprites'
> ```

I believe `self.game.all_sprites` is being called before it's defined or haven't passed the game object into the `Player` object. How do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
from sprites import *
from config import *
import sys

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    def createTilemap(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(tilemap):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == "B":
                    Block(self, j, i)
                if column == "P":
                    Player(self, j, i)


    def new(self):
        self.createTilemap()
        # a new game starts
        self.playing = True

        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.blocks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.enemies = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
        self.attacks = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

        self.createTilemap()

    def events(self):
        #game loop events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.playing = False
                self.running == False

    def update(self):
        # game loop updates
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()

    def main(self):
        # game loop
        while self.playing:
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()
        self.running = False

    def game_over(self):
        pass

    def intro_screen(self):
        pass

g = Game()
g.intro_screen()
g.new()
while g.running:
    g.main()
    g.game_over()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: The lines surrounding that error message would tell you (and us) exactly *where* the problem arises. Without, we would have to guess. **Please add the *full* error message!** Also, *does* your Game class *have* something called `all_sprites`?

Comment: And where is the `Player` class code?

Comment: If `Player` or `Block` end up calling the `draw` or `update` methods, then yes, that's what you'd see.  You call `createTilemap` twice inside `new`.  I suspect you want to delete the first one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146, and make sure that other people can reproduce the problem. Exclude things that are *not* required to cause the problem. For example, *check whether* removing the stuff that handles the "blocks" or the "player" solves the problem. If it doesn't, then we don't need that part to reproduce, so cut it out of your example. If it does, then that helps you track the problem down. Dig in further there.

Comment: You should also try [this advice](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It's also not generally clear how you intend for the code to work, at a structural level. In particular: when you do `Block(self, j, i)`, *what is supposed to keep track of* the `Block` instance? Is it automatically registering itself somewhere when created? In the long run, you may well find this is not the easiest organizational scheme to get your head around.

Answer (score 1):

Your error-message complains that the object or instance of class `Game` has not attribute `all_sprites`.

### Stacktrace analysis

First let's search for the error on the bottom of the stacktrace (or *traceback*). Then analyse the cause step-by-step going up the stacktrace.

#### Error Explained

The full stacktrace shows the statement causing this error at the bottom. It is in `line 60` of file `sprites.py`:

```
 File "C:\RPG Game\sprites.py", line 60, in __init__
   self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.blocks
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'all_sprites'
```

An `AttributeError` is quite a common error in Python. You can research for a description, how it is caused and how it can be solved - here on Stackoverflow.

#### Going up the stacktrace

In line 60, when assigning `self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.blocks`, the attribute `all_sprites` of `self.game` instance has not yet been defined.

1. Where is this attribute `all_sprites` defined?
   Found it in the instance-method `new(self)` of class `Game` as:
   `self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()`
2. Was `game.new()` invoked/called before in order to define it?
   Yes, we are in line 60, which is inside the `new(self)` body.
   Assume, you know that `new(self)` is invoked with `__init__`, then also the *traceback* proofs: It was invoked before. Checked that.
3. Was it defined anywhere else before line 60 inside `new(self)` ?
   Let's go up line by line and search for any definition of `self.all_sprites`. Found `self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()`.  Which line is it? As far I can see in your code-sample it's 4 lines before 17: line `21` ?!
4. What went wrong in that definition by invoking `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()`? Was it ever invoked?
   Traceback shows execution aborted at `line 17, in createTilemap`. This is also inside the `__init__` (or `new(self)`) method, exactly the statement `Block(self, j, i)`. Since line 17 is before the definition of `self.all_sprites` we know: The attribute was not defined.

Unfortunately you have not shared the class `Block` with us. So we can't see what happens inside when calling `Block(self, j, i)`.

---

Without further details in your question, the error-analysis and debugging ends here.

Answer (score 0):

`self.createTilemap()` is called twice in the code leading to errors in the `new(self)` function. You just need to remove on of them.